# (gdb) Get the value of the memory address indicated by a register

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, gdb

I'm working on a debugging project that requires me to look through Assembly code using GDB.
One line reads `movzbl (%ebx),%eax`.
I understand that this copies the least significant byte of `(%ebx)` to `%eax`, appending zeros to all the more significant bits.

Now, I'm trying to use GDB to find out what value is held at `(%ebx)`.

`info registers` tells me that the value at `%ebx` is `0x804a6ac`. As I understand it, to get the value at `(%ebx)`, I want the value located at address `0x804a6ac`.
How do I get this value?
I know that, after `movzbl (%ebx),%eax` is run, `%eax` has the value of `0x41`.
Therefore, I suspect that `41` is the least significant byte of `(%ebx)`, but how can I see its entire value?

I tried doing `p/x $0x804a6ac`, but I get `$13 = Value can't be converted to integer.`.
Also, I tried doing `p/x %ebx`, but I get "A syntax error in expression, near `%ebx'."

Comment: what about `p/x *0x804a6ac`

Comment: Looks like I got it: `p/x {char *} 0x804a6ac` gave me `$18 = 0x69626d41`. Edit: Oh, I just saw Jerry's post. That worked as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The "standard" command for this is `x/cx $ebx`.

This is better than `p/x *0x804a6ac` in that you don't have to cut/paste the value of `$ebx`.

Comment: `p /x *(char*)$ebx` does work, or cast to any other type as desired, including an array type to repeat.  But the cast is more typing, and without it you get *Attempt to dereference a generic pointer.*